# Error: on Jhispter, the connection fails except by an alert box (Prompt). how to do?

Tags: jhipster

I started a Project under Jhipster,
I wish I could connect with "ADMIN ADMIN" 
except when I enter the user in input 
it fails, 
but it opens an alert with input
and in the alert the connection works but not in the login pa
and I do not understand why. Do you have any idea?

I tried to redo the code but it gives nothing

```js
login() {
    this.loginService
      .login({
        username: this.loginForm.get('username').value,
        password: this.loginForm.get('password').value,
        rememberMe: this.loginForm.get('rememberMe').value
      })
      .then(() => {
        this.authenticationError = false;
        this.activeModal.dismiss('login success');
        if (this.router.url === '/register' || /^\/activate\//.test(this.router.url) || /^\/reset\//.test(this.router.url)) {
          this.router.navigate(['']);
        }

        this.eventManager.broadcast({
          name: 'authenticationSuccess',
          content: 'Sending Authentication Success'
        });

        // previousState was set in the authExpiredInterceptor before being redirected to login modal.
        // since login is successful, go to stored previousState and clear previousState
        const redirect = this.stateStorageService.getUrl();
        if (redirect) {
          this.stateStorageService.storeUrl(null);
          this.router.navigateByUrl(redirect);
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        this.authenticationError = true;
      });
}
```

Comment: Please, could you post a log of what happens when your login fails? front/back end

Comment: the problem came from jhipster who had not generated all the files